# how to set maximum rows in create table for sqlite

Tags: sqlite, create-table

In MySQL, I can use MAX_ROWS option in CREATE TABLE statement to limit rows number, how might I do this in sqlite? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has no explicit mechanism for this, but you could implement it with a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTable_row_count
BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable) >= 10
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, 'too many rows');
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLite has no such equivalent option.

Your best bet is to run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl` before inserting and checking if the returned count is greater than whatever you want your maximum to be.